# What is the best way to secure a mobile application and a Microservices backend archtiecture

Tags: mobile, social-networking, spring-cloud, spring-security-oauth2, spring-social

I am currently working on a mobile application that will allow a user to sign in via username/password (OAuth 2.0 Password Grant), Facebook, Twitter, or Google. The backend for this mobile application is coded in Spring Boot/Cloud (Java) and makes use of Microservices principles. I have several small services that are discoverable via Eureka and make use of Spring Cloud Config for centralized configuration. They are all exposed to the Mobile device using Spring Cloud Zuul, which acts as a reverse proxy. The Spring Security OAuth 2.0 setup that I have takes in the username and password then returns a JWT token, this token is validated every time a request is made to the backend. I also store users locally in MongoDB and make use of Method Level Security. I want to add Social Login to my application and have it do the following:

1. On the Mobile Device do the OAuth dance and get an access token
2. Send the access token to the server, and using Spring Social create a new User locally and associate it to Facebook/Twitter/Google, and then return a JWT token that can be used to validate requests
3. This JWT token should be created by Spring Security, and I should still be able to use Method Level Security and have local users
4. Basically I want all the features I have with my custom Spring Security OAuth 2.0 Password Grant with Social Login

This is my first attempt in architecting a system, and therefore am looking forward to responses from those with much more experience than I have. I have seen many examples that use Spring Social, but all of them are for Web Apps, not for Mobile, this is where I am currently stuck at.

The questions I have are the following:

1. Is my suggested approach adequate? Are there other approaches that are stateless and better for mobile applications?
2. Is Spring Security OAuth 2.0 and Spring Social Security enough to accomplish this? If so, are there resources that I can use? I have not found many online.
3. Could Spring Cloud Security be used as a solution?
4. Should I consider using a 3rd Party provider for Authentication such as Auth0 or OKTA?

Answer (score 1):

1. using OAuth2 for a stateless solution is in my opionion adequate, because of:
2. oauth2 in general is a protocol designed to be usable in every client, which is able to perform http requests. Since the social nets you mentioned all support OAuth2. If everything goes bad, you still can consume them manually respecting the oauth2 specs, which they implement.

in general I see a problem with "authenticate with XXX and use that token as JWT for my requests". This is not directly possible, because that token is for their resource servers. Instead you need to separate 2 processes: authentication and authorization. In short you can use the socials endpoints to authenticate a user in your backend, which leads to a second oauth2 generation from your authorization server. This can create a JWT using all features from spring-oauth.

3. This libary should used in addition, since it helps to setup a application wide security solution. As example, you keep an own authorizationserver (which authenticates using social login) and several resource servers. spring-cloud-security helps to build things on top of that, as Zuul SSO, hystrix+ribbon powered feign clients respecting oauth2 authentications and so on
4. I don't thing this will help you, because those services primary serve you as an identity provider, while you are going to couple your users identity over social networks

I hope I could clarify your question in some way

Comment: Thank for your recommendations, I will definitely look to see how I can implement a solution with existing Spring technologies and not pay for something like auth0.

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved it by referring two spring example applications. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527308/how-to-secure-spring-boot-restful-service-with-oauth2-and-social-login/39527800#39527800)
steps, you will be able to achieve social sso login with Zuul, Auth-server and multiple back-end REST projects.

Comment: Does this solution work for Social Login from an Android or IOS device? And the creation of JWT tokens that are consumable and usable by Spring Security?

Comment: I have not tested it for Android or iOS native app but it's working in Chrome/Safari browser as website.

Comment: For mobile native app, check [link](http://www.slideshare.net/rohitsghatol/oauth-20-simplified), slide 64 for handling redirect in app. In that presentation they have mentioned how to handle OAuth callback in Android/iOS native app.