# how to Secure Spring Boot RESTful service with OAuth2 and Social login

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, spring-social

I am trying to use Angular 2 Front End application as a client which will consume the resource from Spring RESTful Web Service.

So thought of protecting this web service with OAuth 2 authentication and Social Login (Google and Facebook).

After successful login with Social Login it's not redirecting to the URL (port at which Angular 2 is running in local environment with 3000 port) from which I made the request but its redirecting to 8080 port in local environment

localhost:3000 - Front End
localhost:8080 - OAuth

I followed this tutorial https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/ for the above scenario but they are using JAVA Application as their client and it's handling with annotations.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to achieve social login with multiple RESTful resource by following two example applications, following are the steps:

(1) Checkout https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/tree/master/oauth2

(2) Delete "authserver" folder (We will use auth-server from another project)

(3) Checkout auth-server from social demo: https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-boot-oauth2/tree/master/auth-server

(4) Open application.yml of "ui" project and do following changes:

```
server.port: 9001
server.context-path: /zuul
debug: true

spring:
  aop:
    proxy-target-class: true


security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      client-id: acme
      client-secret: acmesecret
      access-token-uri: http://localhost:8080/oauth/token
      user-authorization-uri: http://localhost:8080/oauth/authorize
      grant-type: implicit
    resource:
      user-info-uri: http://localhost:8080/me

zuul:
  routes:
    resource:
      path: /resource/**
      url: http://localhost:9000/resource
    user:
      path: /user/**
      url: http://localhost:8080/me

logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.security: DEBUG
```

(5) Open application.yml of auth-server and add google properties:

```
google:
  client:
    clientId: <your client id>
    clientSecret: <your client secret>
    accessTokenUri: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
    scope: profile,email
    userAuthorizationUri: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth
    clientAuthenticationScheme: form
    redirect-uri: http://localhost:8080
  resource:
    userInfoUri: https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me
```

(6) Open SocialApplication.java of auth-server :
Add google related bean and filters (similar to facebook and github).

(7) rename application.properties to application.yml of "resource" project 
following is the content of that yml:

```
server:
  port: 9000
  context-path: /resource
security:
  oauth2:
    resource:
      user-info-uri: http://localhost:8080/me

logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.security: DEBUG
    org.springframework.web: DEBUG
```

(8) Now run auth-server, resource and ui projects and hit URL with port 9001 and context /zuul.

Comment: But my UI Project is in Angular 2 and it doesn't have Spring Code. so I cannot change application.properties in UI project

Comment: In above steps, UI project means the Zuul project. You can keep you UI project separate from Spring Boot Jar.

Comment: I am new to Zuul, can I see your code in GitHub? @Hitesh shekhada

Comment: see [this](https://github.com/htshekhada/google-oauth-multiple) link for reference.