# SOA Spring Angular2 OAuth2 Security

Tags: rest, security, spring-mvc, angular, ionic2

I want to secure my app using OpenAuth2 protocol.
should I add it in server side (Spring MVC REST) or client side (angular2 ionic2) or both together?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527308/how-to-secure-spring-boot-restful-service-with-oauth2-and-social-login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your server side and in client side use code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { Resources } from '../../config/resources';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
    private urlLogin: string;

    constructor(private http: Http) {
        this.urlLogin = Resources.getUrlBackend() + "oauth/token";
    }

    public login(usuario) {

        let headers = new Headers({
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa("clientapp" + ':' + "springSecurity")
        });

        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        let client = "username=" + usuario.email + "&password=" + encodeURIComponent(usuario.senha) + "&grant_type=password&" +
            "client_secret=springSecurity&client_id=clientapp";

        return this.http.post(this.urlLogin, client, options)
            .map(res => res.json());
    }

}
```